# What's your filepath location when you're calling from a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to call a script from a controller function, but I am not sure what my current directory is.

The script is located in a assets folder which is on the same level as codeigniters application folder. I can call it using
    require base_url().'/assets/php/script.php';

but I'd rather not use that since it is using http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3 you could use the `__DIR__` constant which gives you the absolute path to the PHP file you are in. If `__DIR__` is not available you could use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php